# Search is skipping first element in linked list in Java

Tags: java, search, linked-list, iterator, skip

beginner programmer here and I am having an issue with the search function of my program, it works like a charm unless you search for the first item in the list. A little background, this program (school assignment), reads in a CSV file, creates a Linked List and Hash Table, and sorts the list. For this assignment we have to allow users to search for a contributor by their first name. As stated before, it works just fine until you search for the first name on the list, George. I added in print lines to print the current value of the iterator, and the output shows that George is infact the first element, however when you search that name it comes up "not found". Here is my code snippet for the search:

```
      Iterator<Contributor> nameIter = contributorList.iterator();
      boolean result = false;
      String searchName;
      System.out.println(contributorData.getFirstName()); //What Name is the iterator pointing at??
      System.out.println("Enter the first name of the contributor you are searching: ");
      searchName = in.nextLine();
      String fName = searchName.toLowerCase();
      String keyName;         
      while (nameIter.hasNext()){                 
          contributorData = nameIter.next();
          System.out.println(contributorData.getFirstName()); //What Name is the iterator pointing at??
          keyName = contributorData.getFirstName().toLowerCase(); //keyName should equal the above value
          if (fName.equals(keyName)){
              result = true;
              System.out.println("\nThe following contributor was found:\n");
              System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-8s %-15s %-17s %s %n", "First", "Last",
                                "Country", "Phone #", "Contribution", "ID");
              contributorData.Print();                 
          }//end if statement           

      }//end While
      if (result == false){
          System.out.println("\nSorry, but that name was not found!");
      }
      System.out.println("\nPress enter to return to the Main Menu...\n");
      in.nextLine();
```

Here is the output when I try to search for George:

George <-- current value at iterator
Enter the first name of the contributor you are searching:
George
George  <--This shows that the value at the iterator should be George, so wth?
Gordon  <--Why is search starting here??
Jean
Mike
Tim

Sorry, but that name was not found!

So yeah, I'm very lost as to what is happening here. I've tried moving the contributorData = nameIter.next(); around, but it doesn't fix the problem or it causes more...any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the route of the iterator on your list is fine, what may be happening is that your data are spacios blank and if it does not get rid of them affects the comparison and therefore can not find it, also verify if it is to reverse order

```
Iterator<Contributor> nameIter = contributorList.iterator(); 
  boolean result = false;
  String searchName;
  System.out.println("Enter the first name of the contributor you are searching: ");
  searchName = in.next().toLowerCase().trim();//it is not necessary to use another variable to downcasing  
        //and add .trim () to get rid of blank spaces that may have strings    
  while (nameIter.hasNext()){                 
      contributorData = nameIter.next();
      if (contributorData.getFirstName().trim().toLowerCase().equals(searchName)){
          System.out.println("\nThe following contributor was found:\n");
          System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-8s %-15s %-17s %s %n", "First", "Last",
                            "Country", "Phone #", "Contribution", "ID");
          contributorData.Print(); 
          //break ;if you only want to get the first match uncomment


      }           
  }
  if (result == false){
      System.out.println("\nSorry, but that name was not found!");
  }
```

Comment: Made all the changes, still doesn't work. Thanks for the tip on not making extra variables though...however still getting the same results, all other names show up fine, only the first one (george) doesn't....could it be somewhere else in my code? This is a Case within a switch...seriously have no idea what's going on...

Comment: assigned to Data contributor before making your first impression?

Comment: Tried that...this sounds weird, but I'm thinking it's a problem with the "George" in the .csv file....it's not skipping the first item, I manually entered other contributors, even named a few george, and I can search and print them just fine...also if I manually enter a name that will be at the top of the list (it gets sorted), I can search and find that as well...it's only that specific George line I can't search for....but it makes no sense :/

Comment: I modified my answer, add .trim () to get rid of blank spaces that may have strings

Comment: I'd kiss you if I could....you put contributorData.getFirstName() in there twice...but anyways, that works. So, just so I understand what's going on here....trim() get's rid of blank spaces, so the George data has a blank space somewhere in the name? Doesn't make sense, because even in the excel file there are no spaces, they are all the same...I mean hey, it works...just weird and I don't exactly understand why

Comment: It may be you have escaped a space at the end of the name so it is advisable to use the trim as space affects the comparison, thanks for watching.

Comment: Nevermind...looked closer at the excel file, there was a space after "George" in the file....ugh, all this headache over a damn space....thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The programme flow looks good except one issue I found, your while loop does not terminate when ever the condition is met. 
I mean when you are searching for George. Once the condition is met the loop should be stopped.

```
while (nameIter.hasNext()){                 
          contributorData = nameIter.next();
          System.out.println(contributorData.getFirstName()); //What Name is the iterator pointing at??
          keyName = contributorData.getFirstName().toLowerCase(); //keyName should equal the above value

          if (fName.equals(keyName)){
              result = true;
              System.out.println("\nThe following contributor was found:\n");
              System.out.printf("%-10s %-10s %-8s %-15s %-17s %s %n", "First", "Last",
                                "Country", "Phone #", "Contribution", "ID");

              contributorData.Print();     
              break; // this will make the flow exit from the loop      //whenever a condition is met.           
          }//end if statement.
```

I hope you should get the result.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but that didn't work. And it does exit the While loop once the name is found...with literally every other name in the list it works fine, it prints the name and everything, then returns to the main menu (this is a case within a switch statement). I added the Break where you suggested, but it didn't change anything unfortunately....

Comment: Is George at your linked list 0th index. If so can you please try replacing your iterator with enhanced 4 loop. I believe you are not performing any remove operation on this list. Enhanced for can also be used.                               for(Contributor cbtr : conteibutorList){.                                         If(searcName.equals(cbtr.getName){. //found result}                }

Comment: I'm a very beginner programmer, only experience is previous classes....never done an enhanced 4 loop...I'll look it up though and see if I can get it to work with that, thank you

Comment: And yes, George starts out at the 0th index...however even if I put a different contributor in the 0th index by manually entering a new contributor, I can search for that one just fine...it doesn't matter where George is, the program says he doesn't exist...even though when I print the list he does. I can search for his ID utilizing the Hash Table and find him though...this is strange and is making me lose hair...

Comment: The I am sure there is an issue you your if condition result == false , can u please make this condition if(!result). &try

Comment: There might be some space at the end or beginning of George in CSV file try checking length using name.length() will make sure data is not incorrect.